# Views filter user fields on both sides

Tags: views, entities

I'm sorry my english is not very well, but I hope you can understand my problem. I try to make a views filter using hooks_view_pre_view to make a double-sided query. I got 2 fields, "gender" and "gender_search". I wish that views filters all users who have the gender that the current user searchs IF/AND the current user has the gender the loaded/other users are searching for.

There are many other filter-options, also based on get_locations, too, that's why I wish to use views.

I hope it is possible to solve my problem and you understand my request, it is difficult to explain.

Thanks